# Any conditioning exercise that can prevent concussion caused by a punch or kick to the head or neck?

Tags: boxing, kicking, punching, brain-injury

I have noticed that during kick boxing every time I receive a punch or kick on the head or even neck I tend to go into concussion. I initially suspected it to be vertigo but it seems more like concussion.

Are there any conditioning exercises that I can do that can prevent a concussion every time I am punched/kicked on the head/neck?

Comment: Did you talk to a medical doctor about this? It does not sound like something that should happen…

Comment: How hard are you being hit?  Are you sure this is vertigo and not concussion?

Comment: @ Sardathrion - No,not yet.     @HuwEvans Quite hard. You are right it maybe concussion as well but it appears to be vertigo,just a layman assessment.

Comment: I m concerned about the kicks to the neck, I don't belive this should be common practice!!

Answer (score 8):

My first piece of advice is to see a doctor.  If you are suffering something other than a concussion, that's important to know.  However, if you are suffering concussions, you are risking your health in a serious way, and that's even more important to know.

**Concussions ARE brain damage**

All the current science points to the fact that concussions produce permanent damage.  The "recovery" from a concussion is your brain re-wiring itself around the damage.  Enough concussions, enough damage, and your brain lacks enough connections to keep it going - and people end up with memory, speech, emotional problems.  Or death.  A lot of high school sports deaths in the US are directly tied to concussions.

If you suffer headaches after any of these hits, you need to end that session of training.  If the headaches get worse AFTER the hit, you should go seek medical care immediately.  Concussions turn to death typically within a few hours to a day after receiving them - as brain swelling isn't immediate - and if symptoms worse, that's your small window to get help.

**Avoiding Concussions**

Let's say you go to the doctor and it does turn out to be some other issue that is treatable, and you're still worried about concussions as a separate issue.

My previous answer about [boxers dealing with head blows](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/4257/1598) sums it up.  You can condition your neck to improve stabilizers, you can learn to block better, and roll with the blows.

However, if it turns out you have been taking concussions this whole time? You need to stop engaging in full contact sports.  The sports medicine teacher I trained under, who coached football, had a rule: 3 concussions in your high school career, and you're out of the sport forever.  It wasn't worth risking your life or permanent disability for fun.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about sounds like a disruption to the vestibular system of the inner ear. Some people are particularly sensitive to disequilibrium from abrupt motion. If this is the case for you, I would recommend seeing an ENT physician. They should be able to run some test and perhaps prescribe medication to mitigate the vertigo.  If you want to try something over-the-counter (OTC), Dramamine may help you, but it does cause drowsiness as a side effect. You should definitely rule out any underlying medical causes for this condition before considering any other options.

Comment: Thanks.Are there any exercises that can be done to condition the neck or maybe parts of the head that helps to strengthen those areas?

Comment: Again, I strongly recommend a consultation with a physician about your reported symptoms. There are several underlying medical causes for what you have experienced, and some of them could be quite serious. If it turns out to be disequilibrium and medication isn't a viable treatment for you, there are some exercises which can help you rehabilitate your vestibular system. You may find the following link useful: http://theness.com/neurologicablog/index.php/why-isnt-the-spinning-dancer-dizzy/